# d3.js collapsible tree - add a layout and be able to expand sub-level and the whole tree separately

Tags: d3.js

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083, am using this.

Is there a way to get a layout with buttons instead of just the circle . I would want say a layout which has some details on the node, and two buttons , one which would expand just its immediate sub level and the other that would expand all the nodes under it till the end.

thanks

Comment: If you study the code of the example, you'll see places where circles are drawn, and where clicking the circles are handled. You can simply replace these parts of code with drawing two rectangles, and two clock handlers for each rectangle...

Comment: perfect, just started with javascript and d3 today, so wanted to know if its doable before plunging into it. thanks again, will check, try and let you know.

Comment: can you point me to any tutorials for this? its kind of hard to grasp from that tree code. beginner here.thanks